# Implementing asynchronous client requests in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, process, thread-safety

Is it possible to implement the following workflow in a Spring Boot application: the client initiates a request to the server, leading to a subsequent call to an upstream service. While the upstream service promptly acknowledges the request, it delivers the actual response to our server through a webhook after a certain delay.

In this situation, is it achievable to have the client's thread pause, waiting for us to append the response received from the webhook, and subsequently resume it to send the complete response back to the client?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement asynchronous client requests using the RestTemplate or the newer WebClient for making HTTP requests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this.

First a sort of sequence diagram of what I think you are wanting to do:

```
  Client (1)----id----> Server (2)-----id---> Upstream
                               <---ack----(3)
                               <-response-(4) Upstream
                               (5)----ack--->
         <-response-(6)
```

To read my untested code, let's assume the client sends `id` to the Server and this sends the same identifier to the Upstream, which sends a `UpstreamResponse` that is passed back to the client.

I have assumed that the `id` from the client is a unique request and there is no chance of two client requests arriving around the same time with the same `id`, and I am assuming the the upstream calls back to the server with that `id` so you can link up the response to the appropriate client call.

I suggest you use `ConcurrentHashMap` to hold the a one-slot queue for the pending answer.  (This kind of map is threadsafe.). The `BlockingQueue` is the synchronisation tool - that the original thread waits on for the answer.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class MyController {

    private Map<Integer, BlockingQueue<UpstreamResponse>> queuesById = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @GetMapping(path = "/endpoint/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UpstreamResponse> getUpstreamAnswer(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        // register interest in later incoming request from upstream service
        BlockingQueue<UpstreamResponse> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
        if(queuesById.put(id, queue) != null) {
            // there was already another request for the same id waiting for a response from the upstream service
            // now what?
        }

        // make some upstream request based in the id given
        // upstreamService.invoke(id)

        // now await the answer from upstream
        // use queue.take() if you want to block forever, else use poll(time, unit)
        try {
            UpstreamResponse upstreamResponse = queue.take();
            // remove used Queue - better to do in an outer `finally`
            queuesById.remove(id);

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(upstreamResponse);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            // handle this
        }
    }


    @PostMapping(path = "/upstreamWebhook/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> runGameAction(@PathVariable Integer id, @ModelAttribute UpstreamResponse upstreamAsyncAnswer) {
        BlockingQueue<UpstreamResponse> queue = queuesById.get(id);
        if(queue!=null) {
            if(!queue.offer(upstreamAsyncAnswer)) {
                // handle error that the queue already had 1 item - expect the offer to be accepted
            }
        }
         else {
            // no thread waiting for this response, what do with the response?
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
    }


    public static class UpstreamResponse {

    }
}
```

Several edge cases to consider, but this should point you in the right direction.